# Wait for successful connection before initializing main activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, wait

I'm developing an app that is using a specific communication protocol. This protocol communicates with electric plugs which can be remotely enabled and disabled. To do that, the application must check if the plugs are connected to the user's Wi-Fi network. If they're not, I'm asking the network's password in a `DialogFragment` and send it to the plugs in order to pair them to the network.

My problem is the following: the user should not have access to the rest of the application if the connection fails. And I don't know how to prevent this access.

I launch the connection test in an `AsyncTask`. In this `doInBackground` method, if the auto-connection fails, a dialog asks for the current's Wi-Fi password:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    if (!m_smartConfig.tryAutoConnectionToWiFiNetwork(false))
        showPasswordDialog();

    return null;
}
```

After submitting it, the app tries to connect again. If the password is correct, everything's good and the app can display the rest of the content. If it's not, I would like it to not show anything and to continue displaying the `DialogFragment` pop-up. How could I do that?

EDIT: here's my custom `DialogFragment`:

```
public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
```

{
    NoticeDialogListener mListener;

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.password_hint)
            .setView(v)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                    EditText valueView = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.password);
                    if (valueView != null) {
                        try {
                            String password = valueView.getText().toString();
                            mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this, password);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    return (dialogBuilder.create());
}

public interface NoticeDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String password) throws Exception;
}
```

}

EDIT 2: to add some details to my problem, the thing is that I can't immediately know if the password is correct or isn't. I have to try to connect to the plugs and wait for their response (success or fail). It's only with their response that I can choose the correct behavior.

Comment: It would be easier to handle this using activity which prompts for the dialog. For example the launcher activity has a login button. When the login button is pressed it prompts for password through the dialog. If the password is correct navigate to the next activity which has the rest of your logic. If the password is wrong you can show a toast and keep the user in the original launcher activity

Comment: The problem is that I can't immediately know if the password is correct or isn't. I have to try to connect to the plugs and wait for their response (success or fail). It's only with their response that I can choose the correct behavior.

Comment: So you need an additional step of parsing the response received from the plugs. Go ahead with the rest if you could successfully connect.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by that? I don't know exactly how long the app will have to wait to receive the response. I'm in an AsyncTask and I need to get a positive response before continuing. It seems that blocking the UI in Android is not a good idea.
Could you please explain yourself more? And thanks for you help.

Comment: Your launcher activity starts a thread for the work which you are already doing in doBackground. All you have to do is override onPostExecute() to get the results of the thread. Depending on the result you can choose to proceed or block the user. For further explanation on AsyncTaks, this is a good reference - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html